# Properties with auto configure not working on spring cloud stream and rabbitmq

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have a config server with the properties and a microservice as consumer.

I've tried to configure maxAttempts to avoid retries on the consumer microservices, but it seems not to work.

I also define the bindings properties on config servers and them works fine. My consumer is listening and receive messages, **but it tries 3 times** and then crash.

This is my application.yml in my config server

```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /cmsrsssitemap/v1

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        sitemap-main-output:
          destination: sitemap-main
          group: cms-microservices-v1
          content-type: application/json
          #consumer.concurrency: 2
        test-job-output:
          destination: test-job
          group: cms-microservices-v1
          content-type: application/json
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          test-job-output: 
            consumer:
              maxAttempts: 1
              requeueRejected: false
              autoBindDlq: true
              #dlqTtl: 5000
              #requeueRejected: false
              #dlqDeadLetterExchange: dltexchange1
              #republishToDlq: true
```

This is the application.yml in the producer side

```
server.servlet.contextPath: /cmsjmshandler/v1

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        sitemap-main-input:         
          destination: sitemap-main
          content-type: application/json
        test-job-input:
          destination: test-job
          group: cms-microservices-v1
          content-type: application/json
```

And this is the lisener. It's throwing a NullPointer for testing purpose

```
@Component
public class TestJobListener {


    @StreamListener(StreamProcessor.TEST_JOB)
    public void testJobInput(@Payload String input) throws InterruptedException {
//      Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("########################### "+new Date() + " Mensaje Recibido");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

StreamProcesor.java

```
public interface StreamProcessor {

    public static final String TEST_JOB = "test-job";

    public static final String SITEMAP_MAIN = "sitemap-main";


    @Input(StreamProcessor.TEST_JOB)
    SubscribableChannel testJobOutputInput();

    @Input(StreamProcessor.SITEMAP_MAIN)
    SubscribableChannel processSitemapMain();
}
```

The goal of this it's making to move failed messages to DLQ, but it isn't work either

EDIT 1: Can't make it work. I've made changes according to Artem Bilan but it doesn't work either.

```
server:
  servlet:
    contextPath: /cmsrsssitemap/v1

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        test-job-output:
          destination: test-job
          group: cms-microservices-v1
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 1
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          test-job-output: 
            consumer:
              requeueRejected: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maxAttempts` is not a `rabbit` property. It is a core one.

There is a sample in the Docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.requeue-rejected=true
```

Comment: input has to be exactly "input" or is the channel name?

Comment: Right, that’s the channel name, so, in your case it is `test-job-output` level

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem, I'll answer it below. Another question, input is better named for consumer o producers?

Comment: So, my answer is correct and has to be accepted. The problem with a `channel-destination` relationship is fully different story.

Comment: You answer was correct yes, but I had to change both parts to to work. Only with you changes didn't work.

Comment: Well. That's not how StackOverflow works. The questions and problems has to be fine-grained. There is really a limit with answer and with commenting here, so, we can't handle here complex problems. Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I put the wrong name on the StreamProcesor

```
@StreamListener(StreamProcessor.TEST_JOB)
```

StreamProcesor.TEST_JOB should be the channel name, nor destination. Updating my question.

Corrected SteamProcesor.java
StreamProcesor.java

```
public interface StreamProcessor {

    public static final String TEST_JOB = "test-job-output";

    public static final String SITEMAP_MAIN = "sitemap-main";


    @Input(StreamProcessor.TEST_JOB)
    SubscribableChannel testJobOutputInput();

    @Input(StreamProcessor.SITEMAP_MAIN)
    SubscribableChannel processSitemapMain();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and it works fine with this (corrected) config for me. If you enable the `actuator/env` endpoint on the client and you can see the properties:

[image]

(I used `input` and a local file-based config server).

Comment: thanks, but was a problem with the name in the SteamListener, put the name of the queue instead channel. Now works fine